# how to change the Icon in a Windows form

Tags: c#, icons

i want to change the default icon of a windows form programm. The problem is, when i select a name.ico file comes this error message:

Argument 'picture' must be a picture that can be used as a Icon.

My Icon is 32X32 pixel. Can anyone say what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This question as already been answered in this post:

[C# Argument 'picture' must be a picture that can be used as an Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333256/c-sharp-argument-picture-must-be-a-picture-that-can-be-used-as-an-icon)

Wingman4l7 Reccomends using this link: http://www.convertico.com/ to convert it to a PNG file format.